# Package PGF Math Error: Unknown operator `c' or `co' (in '{4cos(deg(x))}')

Tags: pgfplots, tikz-styles, plot

For the code given below I am getting the following error:

Package PGF Math Error: Unknown operator `c' or` co' (in '{4cos(deg(x))}').

Package PGF Math Error: Unknown operator `p' or` pi' (in '2pi').

Package PGF Math Error: Unknown operator `p' or` pi' (in '2pi').

Please help

```
 \documentclass{article}
    \usepackage{graphicx} % Required for inserting images
    
    \usepackage{amsmath}
    \usepackage[a4paper, total={6in, 8in}]{geometry}
    \usepackage{graphicx} % Required for inserting images
    \usepackage{pgfplots}
    \usepackage{tikz}
    \usetikzlibrary{shapes.geometric, arrows}
    
    \begin{document}
    
    \begin{center}
    \begin{tikzpicture}[scale=0.8]
    \draw[<->] (-4,0) -- (4,0) node[right] {$x$};
    \draw[<->] (0,-4) -- (0,4) node[above] {$y$};
    \draw[dashed] (0,-4) -- (0,4);
    \draw[blue,thick,->] plot [domain=0:2pi,samples=100] ({0},{4cos(deg(x))});
    \draw[red,thick,->] plot [domain=0:2pi,samples=100] ({0},{-4cos(deg(x))});
    \end{tikzpicture}
    \end{center}
    
    
    \end{document}
```

Comment: numbers are allowed to be part of function names (e.g. `log2`) so you need `4*cos(x)` instead of `4cos(x)`

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Try this:

```
   \documentclass{article}
   \usepackage{graphicx} % Required for inserting images
   
   \usepackage{amsmath}
   \usepackage[a4paper, total={6in, 8in}]{geometry}
   \usepackage{graphicx} % Required for inserting images
   \usepackage{pgfplots}
   \usepackage{tikz}
   \usetikzlibrary{shapes.geometric, arrows}
   
   \begin{document}
   
   \begin{center}
     \begin{tikzpicture}[scale=0.8]
       \draw[<->] (-4,0) -- (4,0) node[right] {$x$};
       \draw[<->] (0,-4) -- (0,4) node[above] {$y$};
       \draw[dashed] (0,-4) -- (0,4);
       \draw[blue,thick,domain=0:{2*pi},samples=100] plot  ({\x},{4*cos(\x r)});
       \draw[red,thick,domain=0:{2*pi},samples=100] plot ({\x},{-4*cos(\x r)});
     \end{tikzpicture}
   \end{center}
   
   
   \end{document}
```

[image]